# Cmd script returning a non zero code, ansible gets a zero code

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ansible

I'm running a .bat script on a server, which simply checks if a service is running or no, something like this:

```
nssm.exe start MyService
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "MyService" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
      exit /b 1
  ) else (
      exit /b 0
  )
)
```

This .bat file is called by this ansible:

```
- name: Start service
  win_command: StartService.bat
  args:
     chdir: "C:\temp"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc != 0
```

But I'm always getting a 0 error code wether it fails or it succeed.
If I run the script manually, and check the `%errorlevel%` it's always showing the correct one ..

Comment: Have you tried using [`win_shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/win_shell_module.html#win-shell-module) and setting its `args: executable: cmd.exe` to see if that helps? I believe you are getting bitten by all ansible `win_*` tasks using powershell, but you are using `cmd.exe`, and they don't always see eye-to-eye; actually, the best possible outcome may be for you to *really use* powershell, given how much more expressive of a shell it actually is

Answer (score 0):

Have  go at this version:

```
nssm.exe start MyService
sc query "MyService" | findstr /I "RUNNING"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```